# Can HeuristicCompletionException in Grails simply be ignored?

Tags: java, spring, exception, grails, transactions

In my grails application i frequently get ***org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is rolled back; nested exception is org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only***. I somehow found that this occurs when any kind of exception occurs inside a method annotated by @Transactional and called inside a method which has its own @Transactional. My Query is can this exception simply be caught and ignored?

Comment: What does that mean is transaction is rolled back nothing to do from your side.

Comment: I am getting this issue randomly, any temporary issue might be causing the transaction to roll back which is not my primary concern. This would be fix in the next login but i dont want this exception to trigger the email that is generated on exceptions.

Comment: What is happening is, one of your nested method call throws unchecked exception, which is causing the transaction to be marked as rollback only. And then some where up the call your code catches the exception. But the transaction has been marked as rollback only and you see this UnexpectedRollbackException error. You can make sure, either the unchecked exception does not cross a transactional method and u catch it before that.. or else either let the original exception propogate all the way up.. or else just ignore this UnexpectedRollbackException

Comment: I am very much clear now about the case, but i couldn't catch the thing about propagating the issue all the way up, could you please give a little more detail. Thanks a lot anyways.

Comment: @SudhirN , does this exception occurs only when save or update or also occurs for read operations?

Comment: Whenever transaction tries to commit

Answer (score 2):

I have got a workaround for this, as suggested by Sudhir in comments, i could replicate the Heuristic Completion issue in one of the methods and found that to not rollback the existing transaction use by the Service we create new transaction per method as :

```
@Transactional
Class MyService {
@Transactional(propagation = PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW)
def myMethod(){
throw new Exception();
}
}
```

annotating @Transactional(propagation = PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW) this would create a new Transaction for the method and suspend the existing transaction. Since this would create new transaction each time the method executes which would definitely be a performance issue for huge multithreaded application so i mitigated this by handling all probable exceptions in each of the methods inside the service class. This would be better.

Comment: This scenario here(the link mentioned below) is also a bit similar to your scenario which you have solved earlier.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63284812/chainedtransaction-manager-throws-heuristiccompletionexception-and-not-rollback/63285758#63285758

I have tried to help the other struggling solution seeker with your post since it's almost the same & is tried & tested.