# ChainedTransaction Manager throws HeuristicCompletionException and not Rollback

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions, distributed-transactions

I have chainedTransactionManager and two different datasources.My problem is MydataSource1 entity has a unique constraint violation in database.Mydatasource1.save work then it pass to mydatasource2.save and then it throws HeuristicCompletionException and mydatasource2.save work and not rollback.What I want rollback without any condition if any kind of exceptions occurs

```
> org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException:
> Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
> execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [MYSchema.UNIQUE_NAME]; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
> could not execute statement\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.data.transaction.ChainedTransactionManager.commit(ChainedTransactionManager.java:177)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:619)\r\n\tat
> org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:372)\r\n\tat

@Transactional(rollbackFor = {Exception.class,Throwable.class}, isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, transactionManager = "MychainedTransactionManager", propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
        public void saveMultipleDBSource() 
    {
    ...........
    MyDataSource1.Save(Entity1)
    
    MyDataSource2.Save(Entity2)
    
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you do `saveAndFlush()` instead of `save()` so any constraint violations are caught earlier before you reach `MyDataSource2.Save(Entity2)`

Comment: I already try saveandflush but still same,because in my scenario contraint is in dblevel not in applicationlevel

Answer (score 0):

**Workaround_1:**

Here, is a [tried and tested similar scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45186944/can-heuristiccompletionexception-in-grails-simply-be-ignored) that seems to be analyzed, discussed & solved already
I'd suggest you, give this a try & go through the entire thread, which is a similar scenario of yours.
Currently, you are getting a state: **STATE_MIXED** whereas he had got a state: **STATE_ROLLED_BACK**

**Workaround_2:**

You can also work on exception handling around your target area since the exception you're getting is an unchecked exception.
As your requirement is clear, if you just want to rollback gracefully then you can try doing the exception handling for this scenario using this [spring documentation link](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.6.RELEASE_to_3.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/3.0.6.RELEASE/org/springframework/transaction/HeuristicCompletionException.html).

I Hope, this helps you somehow or the other. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thank you for answer but  PROPAGATION.REQUIRES_NEW not help me,still same error

Comment: Ok, Can you try working on the exception handling(Workaround_2) around your target code block using the provided spring doc. link as you just want to Rollback.

Comment: I dont understand I already put rollback exception and I add try catch in my code but it not hits

Comment: Firstly, You don't need to explicitly specify rollbackFor = {Exception.class, Throwable.class}, because spring will by default rollback a transaction whenever an error occurs.
See Section 12.5.3 Rolling back a declarative transaction

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-rolling-back


Delete the "rollbackFor" attribute from @Transactional, and then provide your manual try-catch exception handling blocks(which I think should override & catch the exception), around your save() methods.

Comment: I remove rollback and nothing change.In my case try catch cant help ,because after @transactional internal logic got error and I cant catch them

Comment: sory @Aniket when I change all save to saveandflush that time its works,is there any patternt to use saveandflush

Comment: On `saveAndFlush`, changes will be flushed to DB immediately using this method, But with `save`, this is not necessarily true, and might stay just in memory, until flush or commit commands are issued explicitly or get executed via transaction management.

But take a note here, even if you flush the changes in transaction and do not commit them, the changes still won't be visible to the other transactions until the commit in this transaction is done. Hence you can use some sort of transaction mechanism, which issues commit operation for you if everything works out fine otherwise a rollback.